# I need the values of the ranges that are in the ACF graph

Tags: python, arima, statmodels

From the ACF graph, you can see the ranges in blue. I need the value of the range in the ACF graph. Can this be retrieved?

[image]

Comment: so what code gives you this graph?

Comment: i import `from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf` and `plot_acf(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf` function for this:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
acf_results = acf(x=df, alpha=0.05)

acf_results[0] #autocorrelation
acf_results[1] #confidence intervals
```

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html